# using jquery to access urls in an rss feed

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss

I am working with an rss feed and trying to create a template to diplay values from it. At this stage I am just trying to make sure that I can access each value. Currently I am getting empty strings logged out when using:

```
  $(function() { 
      $.ajax({
        url:'clnews.xml',
        dataType:'text',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(xml) {
           $xml = $(xml),
           $item = $xml.find( "item" );
           $.each($item, function(index, value){
           $value = $(value);
             $title = $value.find( "title" ).text();
             $link = $value.find( "link" ).text();
             $description = $value.find( "description" ).text();
            console.log($link);
           });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
      }

  });
});
```

The xml for each item looks like:

```
 <item>
   <title>Antivirus Upgrades</title>
   <link>/backoffice/MyPractice/Education/News/MyPractice_AntivirusUpgrades1113.asp</link> 
   <description>Starting November 14, we will be upgrading your antivirus software to maximize protection from viruses. </description>
   <enclosure url="/backoffice/gif/news/InfoSec_th.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpg" articleUrl="/backoffice/gif/news/InfoSec_lg.jpg" tabletLg="/backoffice/gif/osi/InfoSec_lg.jpg" />
   <guid categoryId="8">68966</guid>
   <pubDate archiveDate="">Thursday, November 13, 2014 15:21</pubDate>
</item>
```

I suspect the issue is that the links contain backslashes. but am not sure how to best fix this. I will not be able to change the formatting of the rss. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .......
    success:function(xml) {
       $xml = $.parseXML( xml ); <<<=====
       $xml = $(xml),
       $item = $xml.find( "item" );
       .......
```

Or better still:

```
    .....
    dataType:'xml', //<<<<==== HERE
    type:'GET',
    success:function(xml) {
       $xml = $(xml),
       $item = $xml.find( "item" );
       ........
```

Comment: I am actually getting the item ok it is only link attribute that I am having an issue with. Also I was having an issue with errors about the xml being invalid, which I cannot change, and that is the reason im using dataType:'text'

Comment: Can you give specifics on what the issues are with `<link></link>` ... as far as I know the slash character is a valid XML character and does not need to be escaped. ... What is the specific error regarding the validity of the XML?